# chmod: cannot access ‘/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/hduser896097807/.staging/job_local89609780chmod:

Tags: hadoop, distributed-computing, hadoop-yarn

i am trying to run a simple wordcount problem on single node setup hadoop but i getting this error everytime,
`chmod: cannot access ‘/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/hduser896097807/.staging/job_local89609780chmod: cannot access ‘/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/hduser896097807/.staging/job_local896097807_0001’: No such file or directory
7_0001’: No such file or directory`

I have corrected some code several times, i doubt it's in hadoop configuration or something. 
Please help me out
thank you in advance .. :)

Comment: Does this hdfs folder exist`/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/hduser896097807/` ?

Comment: @ManjunathBallur In my it doesn't exist. There is a folder of some other user. How do I create it?

Comment: To create a directory use "mkdir" command, as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, for the late response

Actually there were no folders like `/app/hadoop/tmp/`
so

```
sudo mkdir /app/hadoop/tmp
```

and i had to set permissions to the that folders by:

```
sudo chown hduser:hadoop /app/hadoop/tmp
```

It may help someone who have gone through this error.  :)